# Why N=11 in opencv squares.cpp

Tags: c++, opencv

I am checking the OpenCV squares.cpp tutorial. Try different threshold level part of the code using "N" which is defined as a global 11. Why do we need N defined as 11? Is there a meaning for 11 for thresholding?

```cpp
int thresh = 50, N = 11;
    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(timg, gray0, ch, 1);
        for( int l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                dilate(gray, gray, UMat(), Point(-1,-1));
            }
            else
            {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                threshold(gray0, gray, (l+1)*255/N, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please put a sample image, and some more of the code!!(close the "for"s at least)

Comment: Because the author had to pick some number, and 11 was reasonable enough (not too high, not too low). All it sets is how many different threshold levels (equally spaced in range 0-255) to try.